# Erlang error received unexpected tcp data on #Port

Tags: erlang

I retrieve a URL with the following code:

```
geturl(Url)->
{ok, RequestId}=httpc:request(get,{Url,[{"User-Agent", "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; U; ru) Presto/2.8.131 Version/11.10"}]}, [],[{sync, false}]),
  M = receive
        {http, {RequestId, {_HttpOk, _ResponseHeaders, _Body}}} -> ok 
      after 20000 ->
        not_ok
      end.
 io:format("httprequest to ~p: ~p~n",[UrlHTTP,M]).
```

Sometimes I see the following error output:

```
httprequest to "http://www.afbudsrejser.dk": ok
=ERROR REPORT==== 30-Apr-2014::16:53:49 ===
Received unexpected tcp data on #Port<0.4432>
   Data:       <<"\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>\r\n\t</body>\r\n</html>\r\n\n">>
   MFA:        undefined
   Request:    undefined
   Session:    {session,{{"www.afbudsrejser.dk",80},<0.4392.0>},
                        false,http,#Port<0.4432>,ip_comm,1,pipeline,true}
   Status:     pipeline
   StatusLine: undefined
   Profile:    httpc_manager
```

Erlang error received unexpected tcp data on #Port

What is the cause of this error message?

Comment: In the cases where you see this message, what is the value of `M`?

Comment: Please edit your question and add this (it's hard to read as a comment). Is the content of `Body` the one you would expect? Or is there data missing? Also, you might want to check the request with wireshark.

Comment: i add error to question

Comment: data not missing, but i have this error, how to remove it?

Comment: is it possible that you run multiple httpc requests at the same time? From the output it looks like some remains of other requests. I'm also experiencing the problem like that but could not create reproducible scenario yet (but see such errors in production)

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP server you are connecting to is misbehaving. It declares a `Content-Length` header that is shorter than the response it actually sends.

This means the last few bytes the server sends (which include the string `type="text/javascript"></script>`) are not expected by `httpc`, since they violate the HTTP spec. `httpc` [prints the warning message](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/inets/src/http_client/httpc_handler.erl#L542) you're seeing when when it receives unexpected bytes that are not part of a valid HTTP response.

If you cannot fix the server, you can simply ignore this warning. You can also take a look at the [`relaxed` httpc option](http://erlang.org/doc/man/httpc.html#request-2), which may or may not work around this issue.